# clearing datagrid Itemssource in wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rows

I'm using a datagrid in my program,and bind it with Itemssource.
I wanna clear all rows programmatically ,not one by one
and I wanna save my Itemssource so I can't use datagrid.Itemssource=null;
because I can't use datagrid with that Itemssource again, and I dont want to make a new Itemssource each time,in fact,I have to clear my Itemssource programmatically.
now,any idea to clear rows?? 
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a ObservableCollection bind to your DataGrid ItemsSource simply use .Clear()

```
public OberservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection {get;set;}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />


//anywhere
MyCollection.Clear();
```